# Side Bar Floating in IE8

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I have hopefully a quick question and issue.

I have a site where the side bar floats no problem in everything but IE8...it even floats correctly in IE on the post templates but the page templates it doesn't.

You can see the page template here: http://adlinsulflex.wpengine.com/firesleeve/ not, the blue menu if you scroll down should be on the left like you see here: http://adlinsulflex.wpengine.com/firesleeve/thermosleeve-s/

I can't for the life of me figure this one out.

Your help is much appreciated.

Cheers,
Robb

Comment: Please post some code or a jsfiddle with the code integrated, standard. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 176, Column 29: Unclosed element div.

```
<div class="entry-content">
```

If that wasn't the error validate your page here:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fadlinsulflex.wpengine.com%2Ffiresleeve%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks @Rens Tillman - this was the issue. Didn't think to validate the code as it works in all modern browsers and is build of the Twenty Twelve theme which should be flawless.  Careless mistake - Cheers

Comment: What validating can still do these days!

Answer (score 0):

If @RensTillman doesn't answer the question, then possibly a space is missing in the CSS for the important float?

Where this:

```
#secondary {
 float: left!important;
}
```

...should be this:

```
#secondary {
 float: left !important;
}
```